# How to make shiny 'showNotification' scrollable?

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have a shiny `showNotification` which prints warnings and errors. Mostly it works well but sometimes there are a lot of warnings or really long warnings and the user can't see them all. How can I get `showNotification` to scroll vertically?

Here is a reprex of my problem.

```
library(shiny)


shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton("show", "Show")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$show, {
      showNotification(
        "R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt) -- Already Tomorrow
        Copyright (C) 2023 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
        Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

        R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
        You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
        Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

        R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
        Type 'contributors()' for more information and
        'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

        Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
        'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
        Type 'q()' to quit R.

        R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt) -- Already Tomorrow
        Copyright (C) 2023 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
        Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

        R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
        You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
        Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

        R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
        Type 'contributors()' for more information and
        'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

        Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
        'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
        Type 'q()' to quit R.

        R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt) -- Already Tomorrow
        Copyright (C) 2023 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
        Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

        R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
        You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
        Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

        R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
        Type 'contributors()' for more information and
        'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

        Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
        'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
        Type 'q()' to quit R.

        R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt) -- Already Tomorrow
        Copyright (C) 2023 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
        Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

        R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
        You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
        Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

        R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
        Type 'contributors()' for more information and
        'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

        Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
        'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
        Type 'q()' to quit R.

        R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt) -- Already Tomorrow
        Copyright (C) 2023 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
        Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

        R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
        You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
        Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

        R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
        Type 'contributors()' for more information and
        'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

        Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
        'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
        Type 'q()' to quit R."
      )
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add some CSS to your `ui` in order to style the selector `.shiny-notification`. The key here is to define `overflow: auto;` for making it scrollable.

```
    ui = fluidPage(actionButton("show", "Show"),
                   tags$head(tags$style(
                       HTML(
                           ".shiny-notification {
                                position:fixed;
                                top: 10px;
                                bottom: 0px;
                                left: 300px;
                                right: 300px;
                                overflow: auto;
                            }
                           "
                       )
                   ))),
```

[image]